# Standard behavior of tellp on empty ostringstream

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, stringstream

I have a question on the standard behavior of calling `tellp` on an empty `ostringstream`. I have a function foo which calls `tellp` the first thing:

```
void foo(std::ostream& os)
{
    std::ostream::pos_type pos = os.tellp();
    // do some stuff.
}

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    foo(os);
}
```

In Visual Studio 2005, calling this function with a newly created and empty `ostringstream` results in the `pos` variable to be set to an invalid `pos_type`, which in Visual Studio 2005 is set to `pos_type(_BADOFF)`.

`ofstream` does not have the same behavior, where `tellp` returns `pos_type(0)`, which is a valid `pos_type`.

Is this standard conforming behavior? Is this behavior consistent with other compilers?

Comment: In codeblocks IDE, pos is set to 0 where as in MSVC++ 6.0 IDE it is -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

27.6.2.4:

```
pos_type tellp();
```

> Returns: if fail() != false, returns
>   pos_type(-1) to indicate failure.
>   Otherwise, returns
>   rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, *cur*, *out*).

And *pubseekoff* returns -1 on fail. But am not sure why this happens for you in the case of *ostringstream*, maybe was too tired to find the words about *undefined* or *implementation-dependent*. Using my common sense I would say that for *ostringstream* this should give 0, for default constructed ostream -1, and for ostream with freshly opened file 0.

Comment: I agree that this should give 0 for `ostringstream`, so I guess this is a bug in VS2005's C++ Standard Library.